# Do dictionaries in Python offer the best way to formulate switch-like statements?

Tags: python, dictionary, conditional-statements, switch-statement

I'm hoping there's no performance or other disadvantage in attempting to avoid long chains of conditional if/elif statements this way:

```
errstr = {404: "404 Not Found",
          405: "405 Method Not Allowed"}
if code in errstr:
       print errstr[code];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they're the best solution, because they are implemented as hash tables, giving approximately constant lookup times (if the hash function is good). Binary trees would give logarithmic lookup time, `if` chains linear time. Hash tables are usually the way to go if one has to represent a mapping from a not-too-large finite set to some other set.

BTW, Python is a very good language for learning, because in Python, often the simplest solution is also the best one.

Comment: Thank you so much Philipp! I really appreciate your timely answer and insight.

Comment: @Ryan: As an opposite I'd name languages such as Bash: if you want to iterate over array *X*, you have to specify it as `"${X[@]}"`—leaving out the braces or the brackets or the quotes will do something, but not what was intended. Here the correct solution is most complicated.

Comment: That's a syntax-ism, not a "solution".

Comment: I still haven't figured out how to include print statements in Python dictionaries, though. In such cases, the output of the function seems unpredictable: http://ideone.com/aL9EUE